# Story about a conversation in a cafe. The waiter is Hitler

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

Read maybe ten years ago.  Fairly new then, maybe.  The story takes place in a cafe in Europe between two people.  One, I think, was a time traveler or maybe not.  The other either an up-and-coming political figure or a scientist of some sort.  The kicker of the story is that the unassuming waiter is actually Adolf Hitler

Comment: Any dragons involved?  This seems like one tiny fragment of *Roadmarks* by Roger Zelazny.

Comment: No and no. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I asked the question on another site and got an answer fairly quickly.  The story is ["Inspiration"](https://www.baen.com/Chapters/9781476781211/9781476781211___5.htm) by Ben Bova.  I got a very pertinent detail wrong in my memory of the story.  Hitler wasn't the waiter, but he was present as a boy, helping the waitress, who was his mother.  The scientist was Einstein.  H.G. Wells was there as well.  Perhaps this story bubbled up in my mind because of the recent death of Bova, as well as my reading of a similarly themed story by Barry Malzburg (Shiva).  Thanks to all and sorry for sending you down the wrong rabbit hole.

Comment: So that story takes place before WWI.

Answer (score 7):

"[Catch That Zeppelin!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catch_That_Zeppelin)" is a 1975 alternate history short story by American writer Fritz Leiber. It was first published in The Magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction.

When Fritz Leiber sees a Zeppelin moored at the Empire State Building one afternoon in 1973, he realizes that he has shifted into another timeline — one where a more decisive defeat of Germany at the end of the First World War led to greater international prosperity and a deeper, more acceptable peace, with the result that America was willing to sell Germany helium for use in airships, thereby preventing the Hindenburg disaster. Also, the year has changed from 1973 to 1937, and Leiber has become a patriotic-but-peaceful German airship engineer named Adolf Hitler.

Comment: Did this alternate timeline have any of the features described above (e.g. Hitler as a waiter, etc)?

Comment: The narrator/protagonist of *Catch that Zeppelin* is Hitler. He is not a waiter.

Comment: At the end there is a scene, where the protagonist interacts in a restaurant with a waiter, maybe Emsley Wyatt misremembered.

Comment: What happened to the Soviet Union, Japan and China in that timeline? That's the pivot. People are so eurocentric. Who cares about Yurop!

Comment: @Spoeken This is the one I thought of immediately. Thanks for posting an answer so OP has a chance to confirm or refute it.

Comment: I've read "Zeppelin" and am sure that it's not the story in question.  The incident in the cafe, or maybe it was a beirgarten, is not a sideplot but rather the central point of the story.  Nor is the story I'm looking for one in which the author appears as a character in his own work.  The revelation that the waiter is Hitler is subtle, rather than overt.  And "Zeppelin" is too old and, I think, too long.